# How to display posts and pages on a WordPress tag page?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

**Adding tags to WordPress pages**

I try to display both posts and pages that are tagged with the same tag when I'm on a WordPress tag page. I'm using some custom code to be able to add the tag functionality to WordPress pages. Adding a tag to a page works and I can also display the tag on the page when I'm using `<?php the_tags(); />` in a page template.

I'm using this code (in my child theme functions.php) to register the tag functionality to pages:

```
// Add tag support to pages
function tags_support_all() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'page');
}
add_action('init', 'tags_support_all');
```

**The issue - Pages with tags are not being displayed on the tag page**

I can't seem to find a way to get these pages displayed on the tag page. It only shows the posts that are tagged with the same tag. No pages. I use the code below to try and update the pre_get_posts query by setting the post_type to 'any'. It's an (old) snippet that I found on Google why I was searching for a solution. I'm not sure if this is still the way to go, but I couldn't find any working alternatives.

```
// Display all post types on tag pages
function tags_support_query($wp_query) {
    if ($wp_query->get('tag')) {
        $wp_query->set('post_type', 'any');
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'tags_support_query');
```

Any ideas on how to get this working?

**Some extra information**:

- WordPress version 5.7.2.
- I'm using a theme and (custom) child theme combination. The theme uses the Gutenberg editor.
- The above code snippets are added to the child theme functions.php
- There's no specific tag.php or archive.php. The tag page uses the default index.php to display the tag page. This index.php is also used on categories, archives, etc.

Comment: A custom query would be the easiest direction to go. Would that be an option? And can you the specific parts of the `index.php` regarding the output of the posts + pages.

Comment: I would prefer adding something in the functions.php, but a custom query should be fine as well. I'm using the Neve theme for WordPress and it's default index file. You can find the source on GitHub: https://github.com/Codeinwp/neve/blob/master/index.php . I could create a tag.php file in the child theme folder with a custom query in it. Do you have some suggestions for that query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new file that you can use for all Tags and call it `tag.php`. This will allow all Tag related archive pages to be rendered by this file. Other categories and archives will remain untouched.

In this new file copy all contents of `index.php` but add the following code in the top of the file.

```
/**
 * Get the Term ID of the current term.
 */
$term = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $term->term_id;

/**
 * Get all posts and pages with the current term.
 */
$args = array(
  'post_type'      => array('post', 'page'),
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'post_status'    => 'publish',
  'tax_query'      => array(
     array(
       'taxonomy'    => 'post_tag',
       'field'       => 'term_id',
       'terms'       => [$term_id]
     )
   )
);

/**
 * Create a new query.
 */
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Then replace all occurences where the following occurs:

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
// replace with
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
```

,

```
while ( have_posts() ) {
// replace with
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
```

and

```
the_post();
// replace with
$query->the_post();
```

Then after the closing bracket of the `while` loop, add `wp_reset_postdata();` to ensure that the post data related to the page has been reset. (otherwise the latest post in the loop will be considered the post of the page).

This should (at least) give you access to the posts and pages that have the `post_tag` term that corresponds with the page.

Comment: I tried this solution twice but somehow it doesn't work. The pages don't show up on the tag page. Only the post are being displayed. I'm 100% sure that my custom `tag.php` is working because I've also added a custom CSS class to check it. My example page should also have the tag attached to it because I see the tag showing up on the page when I add `<?php the_tags(); />` to the specific page template. What could be wrong? Could it be that the theme is doing something that blocks it? Something like the `do_actions`? Or `$current_post_type`?

Comment: I did some further digging and maybe this info will help: When I echo the `$current_post_type` in tag.php, the value is always "page". I also looked at this file: 
https://github.com/Codeinwp/neve/blob/master/inc/views/template_parts.php . It has some render_post function on like 31.

Comment: You can check if the loop works by outputting `the_title();` after `$query->the_post();`. If the loop functions, you should see multiple titles of posts and pages corresponding with the tag of the current page. That should give you an indication. But other than that, I wouldn't know for sure how to implement it without having an environment to test in.

Comment: That works Emiel! I've tested it on several tag pages and the titles of pages & posts are both returned. So the loop functions like it should. So I'm really wondering what happens inside of the loop. It works with posts but not with pages.

Comment: I saw this part on line 121 in the index.php: `get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );`.  That content file seems to call a custom hook called `neve_blog_post_template_part_content`. which at the end results in the `render_post` function on line 31 in template_parts.php. The `render_posts` function seems to call the `archive-post` view with this line `$this->get_view( 'archive-post', $args );`. It passes some "post" arguments. Maybe that prevents the rendering of pages?

Comment: Great! I was looking at the same thing. These "post" arguments don't seem to trigger a new query or overwrite any data. I believe that the theme doesn't know what to render in case of a page post. I think that in case of a page, the `get_template_part` function will look for `template-parts/content-page`. But it should render the `template-parts/content` file instead, since that has the same logic as the post. Try removing `get_post_type()` by removing the second param on line 121 and see what happens.

Comment: Awesome! Removing that `get_post_type()` did the job! Thank you very much! Posts & pages are now being displayed on the tag.php pages. I didn't thought of this before, but I think I need to create a new loop. My pages don't have custom categories and both don't need an excerpt on the tag.php pages. I'll try to create some custom loop where I just need the title, link, featured image.